# Spotlight search stopped suggesting my frequently-used app

Tags: macos, spotlight, search

I use Spotlight Search frequently to launch apps on my Mac, and it works perfectly. I use Telegram Desktop frequently by typing a few letters in Spotlight Search. I just type a few letters and tap enter and it opens. Simple as that.

However, today it started not finding it. Instead, it shows this:

[image]

The app is there, launches perfectly manually from Applications folder:

[image]

But in Spotlight Search, it's not being suggested. I've got Applications option ticked in Spotlight options from System Preferences (though I haven't touched it anyway) and it suggests other apps from the Applications folder with no problem. I am on macOS 10.12.6.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the same thing happened to me today... I just shut down my Mac and restarted it after a while and for now it's fixed...

I hope it will stay this way, nd it might be a solution for you as well!