# Spotlight search not including Applications in the result [MacOS Mojave]

Tags: macos, mojave, spotlight

[image: Spotlight search not searching including Applications in the result MacOS Mojave]

Problem:  apps not being included in the result. None of the apps show up.
Expected behavior: FaceTime App included a top hit.

- Tried re-indexing by adding and then removing from Privacy tab in spotlight settings. No change.
- Rebooted multiple times. No change.

followed the suggestions in this two links as well. No change.

[Spotlight search stopped suggesting my frequently-used app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293773/spotlight-search-stopped-suggesting-my-frequently-used-app)

[Single application not showing up in Spotlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236741/single-application-not-showing-up-in-spotlight)

Sys info :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running several test Mojave (10.14.3) macs in my work environment before I am deploying it to our macs.

I do not seem to have a similar issue, as can be seen with these screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How did you install Mojave? A fresh clean install? Or was it updated from HFS/APFS High Sierra?

What happens when you run the program, close it, and then try to spotlight the app? Does it show then?

I found this, not sure if this was tested with Mojave but might point you to right direction:
[Applications Don't Show Up in Spotlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62715/applications-dont-show-up-in-spotlight)

Comment: It's not a fresh install. I have been updating to the most available release every time it became available. I never had an issue with spotlight search before, I started having the issue with apps first and now nothing other than my browsing history and notes (from the Notes app) gets indexed.

Comment: I followed the link you attached and it showed me how to disable and re-enable indexing using the `modutil` command and that fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: No Problem glad that helped!

Answer (score 4):

I ran `sudo mdutil -E /Applications` and it worked for me on Big Sur